# Prediction of poisson regression

Tags: r, plot, regression, glm, predict

I'm currently working on a data set with the model

```
glm1 <- glm(FALL ~ GRP + AGE + SEX + offset(log(FU)), family=poisson, data=dat)
```

Now I need to make a prediction of the amount of falls in one year for a female who's in the control group.

I need to do the `predict` function, but I'm not sure how. I tried to do several things and last tried this:

```
levels(dat$GRP)
levels(dat$SEX)
SEX="FEMALE"
GRP="CONTROL"
FU="12"
y<- predict(glm1, type = 'response')
plot(x=dat$AGE[order(dat$AGE)],y=y[order(dat$FALL)],type='l')
```

But this gives me only a weird looking plot. What do I need to do?

---

**Edit: data added on request for reproducibility**

```
dat <- structure(list(FALL = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), GRP = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("CONTROL", "TAI CHI"), class = "factor"), 
FU = c(18, 12, 17, 4, 23, 16, 22, 24, 23, 11, 22, 9, 23, 
8, 20, 17, 23, 17, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 16, 14, 21, 20, 21, 
7, 22, 19, 12, 15, 21, 24, 11, 23, 21, 10, 15, 19, 19, 16, 
24, 17, 23, 16, 17, 18, 18, 20, 8, 21, 16, 15, 19, 23, 14, 
13, 6, 16, 18, 9, 7, 16, 14, 16, 18, 13, 12, 15, 22, 17, 
17, 20, 21, 11, 24, 9, 13, 24, 12, 21, 20, 19, 17, 21, 15, 
17, 11, 24, 10, 18, 9, 16, 19, 6, 13, 22, 18, 10, 15, 14, 
21, 21, 5, 24, 21, 11, 23, 21, 16, 22, 6, 24, 18, 21), AGE = c(71, 
81, 71, 79, 77, 79, 76, 86, 75, 75, 76, 83, 71, 80, 77, 79, 
77, 74, 83, 81, 83, 79, 74, 79, 78, 85, 82, 71, 81, 78, 82, 
74, 73, 75, 83, 78, 83, 83, 65, 75, 75, 75, 75, 78, 80, 69, 
80, 73, 74, 79, 76, 78, 70, 77, 77, 76, 84, 71, 73, 76, 80, 
77, 74, 78, 68, 76, 77, 76, 72, 72, 76, 82, 72, 80, 78, 83, 
80, 73, 79, 75, 79, 75, 80, 77, 81, 78, 74, 79, 78, 74, 79, 
77, 77, 85, 79, 73, 78, 73, 70, 68, 74, 82, 75, 77, 77, 73, 
73, 83, 74, 87, 76, 81, 77, 78, 66, 79, 82), SEX = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("FEMALE", 
"MALE"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("FALL", "GRP", "FU", 
"AGE", "SEX"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -117L))
```

Kind regards.

---

**Edit: question on confidence interval**

I have one more question. I created the confidence intervals like this:

```
prs <- predict(glm1, newdata = newdat, type = "response", se.fit=TRUE)
newdat$pred <- prs[[1]]
newdat$se <- prs[[2]]
newdat$lo <- newdat$pred - 1.96 * newdat$se 
newdat$up <- newdat$pred + 1.96 * newdat$se
```

But is it possible to plot this in the same graph?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will add it :)

Comment: I'm using this one: glm1 <- (glm (FALL ~ GRP + AGE + SEX + offset (log(FU)), family=poisson, data=dat))

Comment: Oke Thanks a lot! I will try, and see if it works :)

Comment: I want to set FU to 12 months. But adding FU="12" gives me an error. Do I need to add continious variables in another way?

Comment: yes , sorry that's what i meant indeed. Only now it gives the error: Error in order(newdat$AGE) : argument 1 is not a vector.  This was not when I left out FU. Do you maybe know how to fix it?

Comment: I have one more question. I created the confidence intervals like this: prs<-predict(glm1, newdata = newdat, type = "response", se.fit=TRUE)
newdat$pred<-prs[[1]]
newdat$se<-prs[[2]]
newdat$lo<-newdat$pred-1.96*newdat$se
newdat$up<-newdat$pred+1.96*newdat$se     But is it possible to plot this in the same graph?

Comment: do you maybe know which commands I need to use to compute it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `predict`, you need to set `newdata`. Simply calling `predict` without `newdata` will just return fitted values. So your `predict` call is essentially getting you `glm1$fitted.values`.

Look, you want prediction for `SEX == "FEMALE"` from `GRP == "CONTROL"` with `FU == 12`. Use

```
## I use `AGE = 65:87` because this is what `range(dat$AGE)` gives
## we must provide all covariates used in model formula to make `predict` work
## recycling rule is applied here.
## `GRP`, `SEX` and `FU` are given a single value, while `AGE` has length 23
## they will be recycled 23 times
newdat <- data.frame(AGE = 65:87, GRP = "CONTROL", SEX = "FEMALE", FU = 12)
pred <- predict(glm1, newdata = newdat, type = "response")
plot(newdat$AGE, pred, type = "l")
```

[image]

Initially I suggested:

```
newdat <- subset(dat, GRP == "CONTROL" & SEX == "FEMALE" & FU == 12)
```

but this is a bad idea. It will give you an empty data frame, since there are no matching columns with selection criteria in your `dat`.

---

**Follow-up (actually more worth answering than above)**

> I have one more question. I created the confidence intervals like this:

```
prs <- predict(glm1, newdata = newdat, type = "response", se.fit=TRUE)
newdat$pred <- prs[[1]]
newdat$se <- prs[[2]]
newdat$lo <- newdat$pred - 1.96 * newdat$se 
newdat$up <- newdat$pred + 1.96 * newdat$se
```

> But is it possible to plot this in the same graph?

Your confidence interval is not correctly computed. Response is not normally distributed, so you can't use `1.96`. Linear predictor is asymptotically normal, so you need produce confidence band for linear predictor, then transform it to response scale using inverse link function.

```
ginv <- glm1$family$linkinv  ## inverse link function
prs <- predict(glm1, newdata = newdat, type = "link", se.fit=TRUE)
newdat$pred <- ginv(prs[[1]])
newdat$lo <- ginv(prs[[1]] - 1.96 * prs[[2]])
newdat$up <- ginv(prs[[1]] + 1.96 * prs[[2]])
```

To plot them on the same plot, you can use `plot` + `lines`:

```
with(newdat, plot(AGE, pred, type = "l", ylim = c(min(lo), max(up)) ))
with(newdat, lines(AGE, lo, lty = 2))
with(newdat, lines(AGE, up, lty = 2))
```

[image]

Or, you may use `matplot`:

```
matplot(newdat[c("pred", "lo", "up")], type = "l", col = 1, lty = c(1, 2, 2))
```

Comment: Aah, thank you so much! This really explains a lot! Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you so much! You really made my day! :) Thank you!!

Comment: I'm wondering if I take the follow up for 12 months. do I state that as FU=12 or as something else? I tried to do it with 0:12 but that doesn't work, and also 4:12 (minimum) doens't work. Do you maybe have any tips?